# Should I use a Spring singleton bean to build up an email message?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

From a `@Service` class, I'm calling several methods on other `@Service` classes. The service methods do some work and add some text to an email message. That email message is sent to admins to let them know of the work that was done.

Here's a simple example but in general the email message may be appended within any service method including ones that are not directly called by the `MainService`. Similar to logging, The message is always appended to an existing message. It is not modified in any other way.

```
@Service
public class MainService {    

   private final Service1 service1;
   private final Service2 service2;
   private final Mail mail;

   public void doWork() {

       StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();

       List<Item> items = service1.method1(emailMessage);
       Employee employee = service1.method2(emailMessage);
       service1.method3(emailMessage);

       service2.method1(emailMessage);
       service2.method2(emailMessage);

       //send one email to the admins 
       mail.sendEmailToAdmins("Batch process completed", emailMessage.toString());
    }
}

@Service
public class Service1 {

    public List<Item> method1(StringBuilder emailMessage) {

         //some work to remove items
        
        String message = String.format("Following items were removed", items);
        log.info(message);
        emailMessage.append(message);
        return items;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid passing around `emailMessage`? Would it be bad practice to use a singleton to hold state (i.e., email message text) and inject that into each service class?

A few notes are:

- This is not a web application. It's an application that runs on a cron job daily.
- Order of the text appended in the message is not important

Comment: If you only append and do not modify the existing message or the appended text is dependent on the existing message, there is no reason to pass it around. Simply let those methods return strings and append those to the message in `doWork()`. Why would you need AOP for that?

Comment: @kriegaex - Yes. I will only append to the existing message. In the above code, I could replace returning void with String as you suggested. In the more general case though, the method may already be returning another object or primitive. I suppose I could wrap that object in another one that included the String message property.  Thanks for thoughts.

Comment: *"Would it be bad practice to use a singleton to hold state"* In a multi-threaded application: yes. If 2 threads want to build an email at the same time, you're in trouble.

Comment: I would recommend you to declare a separate class for example name it EmailText and only make 'constructor with fields' accessible. You can also add Assert.notNull checks in the constructor. This way you will make sure every field is initialized. Finally after this you can add another method in that class where it can order the text and return you what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on your goal.

The code you wrote appears to work, so your question is really about trying to achieve design-perfection.  There are certainly other patterns you could apply - e.g. some sort of dispatch, or notifier - but why?  If it works, and it's fast-enough, then move on to some other problem.  It it's slow, or doesn't scale to your needs, that's another story.  But in that case, you should gather performance metrics and attack it methodically.

I'm not sure about your singlton idea.  Essentially, emailMessage represents your 'model' in a classic model-view-controller paradigm.  Sure, you could make a singleton out of it, but all that really does is move the model class from being passed-on-the-stack to residing (once) permanently in memory.  If your memory is thrashing with constant new/deletes from creating a billion emails, that might make sense, but I doubt you have that problem.  Singleton likely would not hurt, but what help is it providing?

Don't let Perfect be the enemy of the Good

Comment: I agree for the most part. One more thing: A singleton weould not play well with concurrency. Then you would need a thread-local field for the e-mail message.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MailBuilder class as your domain model and pass it around. Depending which service does what you can have a method for each specific service call. For example MailBuilder.appendForServiceA(args), MailBuilder.appendForServiceB(args). This way you can actually test the builder on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in the right direction, if you see similar interactions from different services with a certain object, you can extract the whole process in the form of Beans.

For example, we can describe the process as follows:

- An EmailBuilder object as input (as the others already mentioned)
- And a series of transformations on that object
- The EmailBuilder now can build an Email Object that holds all necessary transformations

Here is how I would implement this with Spring Beans, the `@Order` annotation here is fundamental to the setup.

```java
    @lombok.Data
    @lombok.Builder
    static class Email {
        private String to;
        private String from;
        @Singular
        private List<String> sections;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    Consumer<Email.EmailBuilder> addFromFieldToEmail() {
        return emailBuilder -> emailBuilder.from("abcd@efghijk.xyz");
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    Consumer<Email.EmailBuilder> addToFieldToEmail() {
        return emailBuilder -> {
            // Get user email from context for example
            // SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            emailBuilder.to("user@domain.com");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(3) // the bean order is taken in consideration when we autowire
              // a list of similar beans. This ensures the processing order
    Consumer<Email.EmailBuilder> addGreetingSectionToEmailBody() {
        return emailBuilder -> emailBuilder.section(
                String.format("Dear %s,", emailBuilder.to)
                + "\nwelcome to our website!"
                + "\n"
        );
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(4)
    Consumer<Email.EmailBuilder> addMarketingSectionToEmailBody() {
        return emailBuilder -> emailBuilder.section(
                "Do you know that if you invite your friends you get 200 Schmeckles in credit?"
                + "[Invitation Link](https://efghijk.xyz/invite?user=123&token=abcdef123)"
        );
    }

    @Bean // creating a Callable bean, and not an EmailBuilder ensures
          // the creation of a new builder each time.
          // An alternative would be to create an EmailBuilder bean of scope prototype
          // see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#prototype
    Callable<Email.EmailBuilder> emailBuilderProvider(final List<Consumer<Email.EmailBuilder>> customizers) {
        return () -> {
            final Email.EmailBuilder builder = Email.builder();
            customizers.forEach(customizer -> customizer.accept(builder));
            return builder;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    MailService mailService(final Callable<Email.EmailBuilder> emailBuilderProvider) {
        return new MailService(emailBuilderProvider);
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    class MailService {

        private final Callable<Email.EmailBuilder> emailBuilderProvider;

        void sendMail() throws Exception {
            Email email = emailBuilderProvider.call().build();
//            mail.sendEmailToAdmins("Batch process completed", email.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your business logic and considering what you've shared I think that using multiple side-effects call on same object, considering that [StringBuilder is not thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), is probably not the best approach.

I would rather return a message from each call from which you want to track the outcome and store them in a data structure, like a stack just to make an example, and building the mail messages considering the data collected.

This approach could be easily tweaked to get a thread safe implementation if needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Bean for sending emails:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("host");
    mailSender.setPort(<port number>);

    mailSender.setUsername("user_name");
    mailSender.setPassword("password");

    ///////////////////////////////
    //Set subject, to
    ///////////////////////////////

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
}
```

And autowire it to your service class as following:

```
@Autowired
public JavaMailSender emailSender;

public void sendSimpleMessage(
  String to, String subject, String text) {
    ...
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(text);
    emailSender.send(message);
    ...
}
```

In your case, because your email to and subject are constant, you can set these parameters at `JavaMailSender` Bean and call `emailSender.send()` wit only one argument that is email body and you don't need instantiate send `SimpleMailMessage` class for calling `emailSender.send()` method. In another language, you message's constant part in your bean and send varying part to send method as arguments.

[Guide to Send Emails in Java](https://mailtrap.io/blog/sending-email-using-java/)

Answer (score 0):

I feel a better way would be to return a wrapper class from your child services. The wrapper class can have two attributes, a generic type `payload` to contain any data that's actually retuned by the service, and another field `summary` of type `String` containing the message that you can use in your email content.

```java
// our wrapper class
class ServiceReply<T> {
  private String summary;
  private T payload;

  // constructors/getters/setters... prefer a builder though
}
```

The your service looks somethings like below

```java
@Service
public class Service1 {
    public ServiceReply<List<Item>> method1() {
         //some work to remove items
        String message = String.format("Following items were removed", items);
        log.info(message);
        return new ServiceReply<>(message, items);
    }
}
```

and your `doWork` method in `MainService.java` reduces to something as below

```java
public void doWork() {

  StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();

  final ServiceReply<List<Item>> replyService1Method1 = service1.method1();
  emailMessage.append(replyService1Method1.getSummary());
  List<Item> items = replyService1Method1.getPayload();

  // other method calls omitted for brevity 

  //send one email to the admins 
  mail.sendEmailToAdmins("Batch process completed", emailMessage.toString());
}
```

This way, though you end up writing a little more code (1 extra line per method call in the above sample), you don't have to bother about passing the message object across methods.